# glmer r significant slope but bootstrap confidence interval includes zero

Tags: r, confidence-interval, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, bootstrap

I am running a generalized linear mixed model in r using glmer.  The slope (year) from the model is significant (<0.05), however, when I bootstrap the slope to get the confidence interval it includes zero. I expected the upper and lower limits be less than zero considering the significant negative slope. Is there something I am missing? Thanks in advance!

Data are included below.

gm1 <- glmer(result ~ year + (1|group),data = tbl_dat_example,family=Gamma(link = "log"))

[image: Model Output and Bootstrap Confidence Intervals]

Data:
id  result  group   year
samp_1  0.41    35  2
samp_10 1.65    9   0
samp_11 2.4 10  0
samp_12 1.4 11  0
samp_13 1.75    12  0
samp_14 1.6 13  0
samp_15 3.2 14  0
samp_16 1.7 15  0
samp_17 1.7 16  0
samp_18 0.38    17  0
samp_19 2.1 18  0
samp_2  0.82    1   0
samp_20 1.05    19  0
samp_21 0.565   20  0
samp_22 0.48    22  0
samp_23 2.9 23  0
samp_24 1.4 24  0
samp_25 0.66    25  0
samp_26 0.24    26  0
samp_27 0.35    27  0
samp_28 0.41    29  0
samp_29 4.3 3   2
samp_3  0.61    2   0
samp_30 3.6 11  2
samp_31 2.1 18  2
samp_32 2.2 23  2
samp_33 2.9 19  2
samp_34 1.7 24  2
samp_35 1.1 25  2
samp_36 2.4 30  2
samp_37 2.4 31  2
samp_38 1   32  2
samp_39 1.5 33  2
samp_4  1.7 3   0
samp_40 2.2 34  2
samp_41 0.75    27  2
samp_42 1.1 22  2
samp_43 0.78    36  2
samp_44 1.4 16  2
samp_45 4.7 37  2
samp_46 3.51    10  11
samp_47 1.49    9   11
samp_48 1.14    8   11
samp_49 2.92    7   11
samp_5  11  4   0
samp_50 2.02    6   11
samp_51 0.604   5   11
samp_52 3.6 4   11
samp_53 1.9 3   11
samp_54 0.727   31  11
samp_55 12.6    37  11
samp_56 6.97    30  11
samp_57 1.05    2   11
samp_58 1.44    1   11
samp_59 0.145   35  11
samp_6  0.59    5   0
samp_60 0.442   29  11
samp_61 0.453   27  11
samp_62 0.622   22  11
samp_63 3.3 16  11
samp_64 0.785   25  11
samp_65 1.08    24  11
samp_66 1.56    19  11
samp_67 5.52    34  11
samp_68 1.47    23  11
samp_69 1.67    18  11
samp_7  2.1 6   0
samp_70 1.04    13  11
samp_71 1.45    33  11
samp_72 1.47    14  11
samp_73 0.736   12  11
samp_74 0.692   11  11
samp_75 0.797   32  11
samp_76 0.141   28  11
samp_77 0.178   26  11
samp_78 0.18    21  11
samp_79 0.186   20  11
samp_8  8.3 7   0
samp_80 0.393   36  11
samp_81 0.359   17  11
samp_82 1.25    15  11
samp_9  21.5    8   0

Comment: Very good of you to question this. Now try `gm1 <- glmer(result ~ year + (1|group),data = DT,family=Gamma(link = "log"), nAGQ = 5)`.

Comment: Personally, I prefer Bayesian Gamma GLMMs (easy with package [RStanArm](https://mc-stan.org/users/interfaces/rstanarm)). I haven't had good experiences with fitting Gamma GLMMs in lme4 ([convergence issues are common for these](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#gamma-glmms)).

Comment: Thank you Roland, this is very helpful. Is there any guidance on the selection of the optimal number of quadrature points? After researching this I came across the following post that suggests that I should look at when the logLik stabilizes, does this seem like a reasonable approach: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/365716/what-does-it-mean-when-a-low-number-of-quadrature-points-gives-a-very-different

Comment: I don't know. I guess you increase it until further increase doesn't change the fit.

Comment: If Ben Bolker suggests it, I'd follow his advice. He maintains lme4 after all.

Comment: I appreciate the quick response.  I think this answers my question.  Thanks again for all the help and guidance!

Comment: Feel free to post an answer.